# MySQL datareader not reading

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to get my data from the database and show in a messagebox but it's not working. I tried to put a dummy messagebox inside my while loop but it seems the code is not going into it also. Are there any ways to do this?

This is my code:

```
 ConnectToDatabase();

 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select Name, LPN From visitors Where password = '@password';", conn);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", decodeStr);

 MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

 while (reader.Read())
 {
     MessageBox.Show("he");

     name = reader["Name"].ToString();
     lpn = reader["LPN"].ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Not sure, but shouldn't `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", decodeStr);` be without the `@`?

Comment: @Stefan - No that `@` is valid

Comment: yes @Stefan previously i used that it worked

Comment: I think you should remove the single quote from '@password'. The correct SQL statement:
`Select Name, LPN From visitors Where password = @password;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to delete single quotes in your `'@password'` part. With single quotes, database manager thinks this is a [string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal), not a parameter.

And that's why your reader doesn't have any data because your password column *probably* doesn't have any string as `@password`.

A few things more;

- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection, command and reader automatically.
- Don't use `AddWithValue` method. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overloads to specify your parameter type and it's size.
- `Name` and `password` are [reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) in MySQL. It must quoted as `Name` and `password`. I know their cases won't match but MySQL does not care their cases for reserved words by default as far as I know.